# How to append I'd after the last maximum number to next numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and I wan to append one with the other.When appended I want the column with I'd as continuous numbers.
Example:

Df1:
| I'd | value |
|-----|-------|
|  1. | ABC   |
|  2. | Bcs.  |

Df2:
| I'd | value |
|-----|-------|
|  1. | Xyx   |
|  2. | Yus  |

Expected output:
| I'd | value |
|-----|-------|
|  1. | ABC   |
|  2. | Bcs.  |
|  3. | Xyx   |
|  4  | Yus   |

I want I'd as seen in the expected df not it's original value, how do I do that? I'd acts as a primary key. Everytime I get a new dataframe I want to append it and I want I'd to be an increment from the last number.

What I tried is

```
Max = final_df['id'].max()
Final_df['id'] = range(Max , Max+Len(final_df))
```

Which results in:

| I'd | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2. | ABC |
| 3. | Bcs. |
| 4 | Xyx |
| 5 | Yus |

Pardon me for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but if it is what I think it is, you want a "concatenation" of dataframes.

The command is pd.concat (see the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'value': 'abc'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'XYZ'}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'value': 'def'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'MNP'}])
```

With pd.concat (`pd.concat([df1, df2])`) you would obtain the following dataframe:

```
   id value
0   1   abc
1   2   XYZ
0   1   def
1   2   MNP
```

By continuous you mean a crescent index, you can the you `id` column as the index from the start:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'value': 'abc'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'XYZ'}]).set_index('id')
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'value': 'def'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'MNP'}]).set_index('id')
```

And use the same command with an additionnal parameter:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

You will obtain:

```
   value
0   abc
1   XYZ
2   def
3   MNP
```

I think it is what you need!